# Issues importing FBPROPHET on Jupyter notebook running on Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-prophet, pystan

I am running Jupyter on CenstOS server. I used 'Conda install pystan' and 'conda install -c conda-forge pystan' but everytime in import either pystan or fbprohet i get the error "No module named 'pystan._api'".

Kindly help

Comment: Do you see fbprophet and pystan in the output of `conda list`? Are you installing it in an environment?

Comment: Yes, its in an anaconda environment.

Comment: Are you using windows? If yes follow the instructions here https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html#windows

Comment: No, its CentOS 7. On my Windows its working fine.